# ampleness in families

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, ample-bundles

Let $X\to S$ be a smooth projective morphism with geometrically connected fibres over an integral noetherian regular scheme $S$ with generic point $\eta$.

Let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$, and suppose that $L$ restricted to the generic fibre $X_\eta$ is ample.

Does it follow that $L$ is ample on every fibre? More precisely, is the restriction of $L$ to $X_s$ (with $s$ a point in $S$) ample?

I am mostly interested in line bundle $L = \omega_{X/S}$. In case $X\to S$ is of relative dimension one, I can prove that the generic ampleness of $L$ in this case implies the ampleness on each fibre. (The genus is constant...)

My schemes are actually varieties over the complex numbers. Maybe that helps?

Comment: If you take a smooth family $X \to S$ of surfaces of general type such that the general element $X_s$ is without $(-2)$-curves and the special element $X_0$ contains a $(-2)$-curve, then it seems to me that $L=\omega_{X/S}$ is ample on $X_s$ but it is $not$ ample on $X_0$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is an interesting case where the answer is positive: when $X\rightarrow S$ is an abelian scheme. This is used to show that abelian schemes over a normal scheme are projective. See e.g. Chai-Faltings, Degeneration of abelian varieties p.6